# How to filter an array of objects inside another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

i got a array of "partners" (like below) and need to filter them by label.

```
  partners: 
  [
    {
      name: 'Partner X',
      solution: [
        {
          label: 'Label 1',
        },
        {
          label: 'Label 2',
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Partner Y',
      solution: [
        {
          label: 'Label 1'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My problem is that i can't filter the "solution" array. My best try was to use a filter inside another filter, like this:

```
    partnerFilter() {
      const partnersClean = this.partners.filter(function(e) {
        return e.solution.filter(function(item) {
          return item.label === 'Label 2'
        })
      })
      return partnersClean
    }
```

The result always display both partners.
I also searched similar cases in here but there isn't with a *object inside a array*, they used indexOf() or includes(), both ways i couldn't make it in this case.

If anyone can help, I appreciate it.

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, filter returns an array, a truthy value, even if empty.

Comment: Read about [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Your inner filter function callback returns an array of solutions but filter function callbacks are supposed to return truthy/falsey. Because that array is always truthy (accidentally), both partners are always present in the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved with the comments help.
Using .some() instead of .filter() to return truthy/falsey values.

```
partnerFilter() {
  const setPartners = this.partners
    .filter(p => p.solution.some(item => item.label === 'Label 2'))
  return setPartners.filter(p => p.solution)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done like this:

```js
    partnerFilter() {
      const partnersClean = this.partners.map(function(e) {
        e.solution = e.solution.filter(function(item) {
          return item.label === 'Label 2'
        });
        return e;
      })
      return partnersClean
    }
```

This will remove solutions with label `Label 1` in the input, keeping other fields like `name` untouched. All the partners will be there in the output, even if there aren't any `solution` objects for them.

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = {partners: [{
    name: 'Partner X',
    solution: [{
        label: 'Label 1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Label 2',
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Partner Y',
    solution: [{
      label: 'Label 1'
    }]
  }
]};

console.log(data.partners.flatMap(i=>i.solution.filter(f=>f.label==="Label 2")))
```